# Salvar xml como UTF8

Tags: c#

Estou consumindo um Webservice, onde o retorno é um XML.

Salvo O XML em um diretório para outro sistema ler.
como faço para salvar esse XML como UTF-8?
O outro sistema ler o conteúdo mas os carácter especial esta desconfigurado.

```
WSHP.XMLServer ws = new WSHP.XMLServer();
var xml = GerarXMLConsulta();
string login = "12000";
string senha = "4329";
var ret = ws.getResultado(login, senha, xml);

using (StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter("D:\\downloads\\Retorno.xml"))
{
    myWriter.Write(ret);
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: mostre um exemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para isso basta usar um dos construtores do `StreamWriter`:

```
using (StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter("D:\\downloads\\Retorno.xml", false, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    myWriter.Write(ret);
}
```

No 2º parâmetro indicamos se pretendemos que o conteúdo seja adicionado ao ficheiro (`true`) ou se deverá sobrepor o ficheiro existente (`false`).

No 3º parâmetro definimos o `Encoding`, que neste caso é `UTF-8`.